# Kubernetes deployment stuck on pending after create pvc

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I'm trying to create a persistent storage to share with all of my application in the K8s cluster.

storageClass.yaml file:

```
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: my-local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

persistentVolume.yaml file:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-local-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 50Mi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: my-local-storage
  local:
    path: /base-xapp/data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - juniper-ric
```

persistentVolumeClaim.yaml file:

```
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: my-local-storage
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Mi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: my
```

and finally, this is the deployment yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.appName }}-deployment
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.appName }}
    xappRelease: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.appName }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.appName }}
        xappRelease: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.appName }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image }}:{{ .Values.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - name: rmr
              containerPort: {{ .Values.rmrPort }}
              protocol: TCP
            - name: rtg
              containerPort: {{ .Values.rtgPort }}
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: app-cfg
              mountPath: {{ .Values.routingTablePath }}{{ .Values.routingTableFile }}
              subPath: {{ .Values.routingTableFile }}
            - name: app-cfg
              mountPath: {{ .Values.routingTablePath }}{{ .Values.vlevelFile }}
              subPath: {{ .Values.vlevelFile }}
            - name: {{ .Values.appName }}-persistent-storage
              mountPath: {{ .Values.appName }}/data
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: {{ .Values.appName }}-configmap
      volumes:
        - name: app-cfg
          configMap:
            name: {{ .Values.appName }}-configmap
            items:
              - key: {{ .Values.routingTableFile }}
                path: {{ .Values.routingTableFile }}
              - key: {{ .Values.vlevelFile }}
                path: {{ .Values.vlevelFile }}
        - name: {{ .Values.appName }}-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: my-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.appName }}-rmr-service
  labels:
    xappRelease: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  selector:
    app: {{ .Values.appName }}
  type : NodePort
  ports:
    - name: rmr
      protocol: TCP
      port: {{ .Values.rmrPort }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.rmrPort }}
    - name: rtg
      protocol: TCP
      port: {{ .Values.rtgPort }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.rtgPort }}
```

When i deploy the container the container status equals Pending

```
base-xapp-deployment-6799d6cbf6-lgjks     0/1     Pending   0          3m25s
```

this is the output of the describe:

```
Name:           base-xapp-deployment-6799d6cbf6-lgjks
Namespace:      near-rt-ric
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=base-xapp
                pod-template-hash=6799d6cbf6
                xappRelease=base-xapp
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/base-xapp-deployment-6799d6cbf6
Containers:
  base-xapp:
    Image:       base-xapp:0.1.0
    Ports:       4565/TCP, 4561/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Environment Variables from:
      base-xapp-configmap  ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:           <none>
    Mounts:
      /rmr_route from app-cfg (rw,path="rmr_route")
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-rxmwm (ro)
      /vlevel from app-cfg (rw,path="vlevel")
      base-xapp/data from base-xapp-persistent-storage (rw)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  app-cfg:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      base-xapp-configmap
    Optional:  false
  base-xapp-persistent-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  my-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-rxmwm:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  10s (x6 over 4m22s)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 persistentvolumeclaim "my-claim" not found.
```

this is the output of kubectl resources:

get pv:

```
dan@linux$ kubectl get pv
NAME          CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM   STORAGECLASS       REASON   AGE
my-local-pv   50Mi       RWO            Retain           Available           my-local-storage     6m2s
```

get pvc:

```
dan@linux$ kubectl get pvc
NAME       STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS       AGE
my-claim   Pending                                      my-local-storage   36m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `spec.volumeName` in your PVC manifest.

```yaml
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-claim
spec:
  volumeName: my-local-pv # this line was missing
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: my-local-storage
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Mi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: my
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer
I add the missing line but the pod is still pending

get pvc:
'''
my-claim   Bound    my-local-pv   50Mi       RWO            my-local-storage   2m39s
'''
describe pod:
'''
Warning  FailedScheduling  48s (x5 over 3m52s)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 persistentvolumeclaim "my-claim" not found.

Comment: Try removing the `spec.selector` from PVC. You can have a look at [this setup](https://github.com/msrumon/microservice-architecture/blob/5261474d58efceea5ab7fad53599476e215e4e7b/k8s/development/volumes.yaml#L8-L35) as reference.

Answer (score 0):

I can see your deployment have namespace `near-rt-ric`.

But your PVC doesn't have a namespace, it probable placed in `default` namespace

Use this command to check `kubectl get pvc -A`